# Mysql Unique constraint issue and liquibase 3.0 when table name is "status"

Tags: mysql, liquibase

I have a table named as status like :

```
| Field    | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| db_table | varchar(255)     | NO   |     |         |                |
| name     | varchar(255)     | NO   |     |         |                |
| rank     | varchar(6)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| style_id | int(11) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

with create statement

```
CREATE TABLE `status` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `db_table` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `rank` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `style_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

luqibase generateChangelog command

`liquibase --url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/testdb  generateChangeLog`

output

`Liquibase generateChangeLog Failed: Error executing SQL select CONSTRAINT_NAME from information_schema.table_constraints where constraint_schema='testdb' and constraint_type='UNIQUE' and table_name='status': Unknown table 'status' in information_schema`

I have no clue why this is an issue and to add more to the puzzle I get this response from mysql

```
select * 
from  information_schema.table_constraints 
where constraint_schema='testdb' 
and table_name='status';
```

> ERROR 1109 (42S02): Unknown table 'status' in information_schema`

Although, I see it without condition `table_name='status'` that status is listed

what is wrong with mysql and/or liquibase ? Is "status" some reserved thing or special purpose that we cannot use as table name .

The same schema works fine with older liquibase version 2.0.5 :(

## Edit

This issue has to do sth with table name as `status`

case A

```
drop table status;
create table statusx
(
    id int(11) unsigned auto_increment, 
    name varchar(20) ,
    primary key (`id`)
);
```

liquibase --url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/testdb  generateChangeLog

works fine

case b

```
drop table statusx;
create table status
(
   id int(11) unsigned auto_increment, 
   name varchar(20), 
   primary key (`id`)
);

liquibase --url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/testdb  generateChangeLog
```

same error:

> Liquibase generateChangeLog Failed: Error executing SQL select CONSTRAINT_NAME from information_schema.table_constraints where constraint_schema='testdb' and constraint_type='UNIQUE' and table_name='status': Unknown table 'status' in information_schema

direct query also fails:

```
select * 
from information_schema.table_constraints 
where constraint_schema = 'testdb' 
  and table_name='status';
```

while this works:

```
select * 
from  information_schema.table_constraints 
where constraint_schema='testdb' 
and table_name='statusx';
```

Works

```
select * 
from  information_schema.table_constraints 
where constraint_schema='ufg_a' 
and table_name='`status`';
```

I think a fix for liquibase would be to use **backticks** around table names e.g table_name='`status`'

Something strange with mysql, I hope **status** is not reserved word in mysql

Comment: Does this behaviour change if you use InnoDB instead of MyISAM? And on which operating system does your MySQL server run? I can't reproduce this on Windows, whereas on SQLFiddle it does happen as well.

Comment: I am on Mac snow leopard ,Mysql Server version: 5.1.44-log Source distribution. Same issue on both InnoDb and MYISAM .